# Codeigniter Multi-lingual language identifier

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, multilingual

I am trying to implement CI uri identifier plugin - http://codeigniter.com/wiki/URI_Language_Identifier/

I set the code on a base codeignitor setup. The “ingore_lang” is set to “en”. I am using “alt_site_url” to generate alternative language links.

Now with english it is working all good, links are fine.

But when I click on any other language, the next set of alternate language urls is not replacing the abbr to the present link. For eg. if Spanish is selected, on the new page the link to italian language becomes:

```
mysite/es/it
```

I have also observed that the alternate language links never show “english” in the list. I assume they are still taking english as current language.

Please help, am I missing something? I applied the code to all specified files as guided.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should remove 'en' from the lang_ignore var, that should add english to alt languages list. Not sure about the es/it part...

Comment: okay, but i did prefer if it did not prepend "en" prefix on default language. The problem is only the "es/it" part. I feel it might be a url waiting to be handled by a function to apply the changed url. Like "current-lang / new lang ". I hope someone has an idea how to handle the language change. I am still looking.

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the code of the implementation you used? I'm also using this in my application and it works fine for me.

Comment: I think this is a wampserver issue. The problem did not come up on my online test server. It is still there on my wamp machine. Seems not a issue with the library.